# User Input in nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

Suppose I am having following code

```
mov eax,3
mov ebx,2
mov ecx,num1
int 80h
```

& I am  accepting 12 from user then what will be the contents of 
[num1], [num1+1] & [num1+2].

please help me

Comment: 1. Please tag your question with proper platform. Is it Linux/i386? 2. How do you check syscall return value? Is your standard input really a 12-byte binary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use a debugger so you can see for yourself.

That said, the `read` syscall expects 3 arguments and you only provide 2. I will assume you really wanted `mov edx, 2` instead of `mov ebx, 2` to specify the length of the read because reading from descriptor `2` (which is `stderr`) makes no sense. I will further assume that you load `ebx` with `0` instead for `stdin`. So if the user enters the digits `1` and `2`, `[num1]` will be ascii code of `1`, which is `49`, `[num1+1]` will be ascii code of `2`, which is `50`, and `[num1+2]` will be unchanged because you only read 2 bytes.

Comment: please help me to learn debugger in nasm. Where I'll get tutorial.